# Show slight tint overlay on Custom Adapter On Long Click

Tags: android, user-interface, custom-adapter

I have a customer adapter which is used to displays a list of items.
I want to show a light white colored tint over the whole custom adapter whenever the user long clicks an item to give a sense of selection (I also plan to place an image over it later on, like a heart or thumbs icon to represent that the item has been liked but that's a different story).

But the problem is how to do it, I can't figure it out and also couldn't find anything on Google.

What would be a simple way for doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you aren't trying to change the value of alpha of your adapterview? Just like-

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ .
  .
  .

  convertView.setAlpha(0.4);   //change the value as per your need
}
```

Even if you don't want to use this feel free to make a `state_selected` item in your selector and use on your adapter `onItemLongClick`.

As per op's need posting this tutorial link, it describes the way to implement an Instagram-like Heart Animation: http://ratiksharma.com/blog/implementing-an-instagram-like-heart-animation-on-android/

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
I suppose `setAlpha()` only works as indented when the background is white otherwise the item shows a colored tint and I don't know how to set `state_selected` using java. Also I think I have not explained what am I exactly going for, if you must have seen the Instagram app, whenever you like a photo a heart icon appears on top of it for a short while, I'm trying to do just that but also with faded-white-ish background over the whole adapter.

Comment: I believe you are looking something like this one: http://ratiksharma.com/blog/implementing-an-instagram-like-heart-animation-on-android/

Comment: That tutorial looks great. Thanks ton :)
Would you post that comment as an Answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Comment: Thank you for informing me about that, posted the link in the main answer. :)